# Pass Parameter to ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I my application I have an application-context.xml. Now I am instantiating The ApplicationContext as:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
```

Is it possible to pass parameter through this instantiation so that those parameters could be used to initialize some properties of some beans?

PS: Not using property file. As the parameters are generated run time, like exicutable jar's location, system architecture, os name etc which is variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution, I am posting it, might be helpful to someone in future:

The Bean class:

```
public class RunManager {

    private String jarPath;
    private String osName;
    private String architecture;

    public RunManager() {

    }

    public RunManager(String[] args) {
        this.jarPath = args[0];
        this.osName = args[1];
        this.architecture = args[2];
    }

    public String getJarPath() {
        return jarPath;
    }

    public void setJarPath(String jarPath) {
        this.jarPath = jarPath;
    }

    public String getOsName() {
        return osName;
    }

    public void setOsName(String osName) {
        this.osName = osName;
    }

    public String getArchitecture() {
        return architecture;
    }

    public void setArchitecture(String architecture) {
        this.architecture = architecture;
    }       
}
```

The initialization of the ApplicationContext:

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
BeanDefinition beanDefinition = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(RunManager.class).addConstructorArgValue(args).getBeanDefinition();
beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("runManager", beanDefinition);
GenericApplicationContext genericApplicationContext = new GenericApplicationContext(beanFactory);
genericApplicationContext.refresh();
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "application-context.xml" }, genericApplicationContext);
```

The injection of this bean reference to another bean of application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="configuration" class="jym.tan.movielibrary.configuration.Configuration" >     
    <property name="runManager" ref="runManager" />
</bean>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This approach is easier http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?71815-Passing-Bean-properties-using-java-util-Properties.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) in your `applicationContext.xml`

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:my.properties"/>
```

This allows you to reference properties directly in your bean declarations using syntax `${myProperty}` assuming the properties file contains a property named `myProperty`.

A sample how you can use such a property:

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.company.Foo">
   <property name="bar" value="${myProperty}"/>
</bean>
```

Another alternative could be based on the [`@Value`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-annotation-based) annotation powered by `SpEL`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need to it without property file. I should have mentioned it before

Comment: @TapasBose, both approaches supports system properties if that's a help to you